# Improve performance of a construction of p-values matrix for a permutation test

Tags: c, r, performance

I used an R code which implements a permutation test for the distributional comparison between two populations of functions. We have p univariate p-values.

The bottleneck is the construction of a matrix which contains all the possible CONTIGUOS p-values.
The last row of the matrix of p-values contain all the univariate p-values.
The penultimate row contains all the  bivariate p-values in this order:
 p_val_c(1,2), p_val_c(2,3), ..., p_val_c(p, 1)
...
The elements of the first row are coincident and the value associated is the p-value of the global test p_val_c(1,...,p)=p_val_c(2,...,p,1)=...=pval(p,1,...,p-1).

For computational reasons, I have decided to implement this component in c and use it in R with .C.

Here the code. The unique important part is the definition of the function Build_pval_asymm_matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void Build_pval_asymm_matrix(int * p, int  * B, double  * pval, 
                             double * L, 
                             double * pval_asymm_matrix);
// Function used for the sorting of vector T_temp with qsort
int cmp(const void *x, const void *y);

int main() {
    int B = 1000; // number Conditional Monte Carlo (CMC) runs
    int p = 100; // number univariate tests

// Generate fictitiously data univariate p-values pval and matrix L. 
// The j-th column of L is the empirical survival 
// function of the statistics test associated to the j-th coefficient 
// of the basis expansion. The dimension of L is B * p.

// Generate pval
double pval[p];
memset(pval, 0, sizeof(pval)); // initialize all elements to 0
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    pval[i] = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
}

// Construct L
double L[B * p];
// Inizialize to 0 the elements of L
memset(L, 0, sizeof(L)); 
// Array used to construct the columns of L
double temp_array[B];
memset(temp_array, 0, sizeof(temp_array)); 
for(int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
    temp_array[i] = (double) (i + 1) / (double) B;
}
for (int iter_coeff=0; iter_coeff < p; iter_coeff++) { 
// Shuffle temp_array
    if (B > 1) {
       for (int k = 0; k < B - 1; k++) 
       {
         int j = rand() % B;
         double t = temp_array[j];
         temp_array[j] = temp_array[k];
         temp_array[k] = t;
       }
   }
    for (int i=0; i<B; i++) {
        L[iter_coeff + p * i] = temp_array[i];  
    }   
}

double pval_asymm_matrix[p * p]; 
memset(pval_asymm_matrix, 0, sizeof(pval_asymm_matrix));
// Construct the asymmetric matrix of p-values
clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;

start = clock();
Build_pval_asymm_matrix(&p, &B, pval, L, pval_asymm_matrix); 
end = clock();

cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("TOTAL CPU time used: %f\n", cpu_time_used);

return 0;
}

void Build_pval_asymm_matrix(int * p, int  * B, double  * pval, 
                             double * L, 
                             double * pval_asymm_matrix) {
    int nbasis = *p, iter_CMC = *B;
    // Scalar output fisher combining function applied on univariate
    // p-values
    double T0_temp = 0;
    // Vector output fisher combining function applied on a set of
    //columns of L
    double T_temp[iter_CMC];
    memset(T_temp, 0, sizeof(T_temp));

    // Counter for elements of T_temp greater than or equal to T0_temp
    int count = 0;
    // Indexes for columns of L
    int inf = 0, sup = 0; 

    // The last row of matrice_pval_asymm contains the univariate p-values
    for(int i = 0; i < nbasis; i++) {
        pval_asymm_matrix[i + nbasis * (nbasis - 1)] = pval[i];
     }

     // Construct the rows from bottom to up
     for (int row = nbasis - 2; row >= 0; row--) {
         for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
             T0_temp = 0;
             memset(T_temp, 0, sizeof(T_temp));
             inf = col;
             sup = (nbasis - row) + col - 1;
             // Combining function Fisher applied on 
             // p-values pval[inf:sup] 
             for (int k = inf; k <= sup; k++) {
                 T0_temp += log(pval[k]);
             }
             T0_temp *= -2;

             // Combining function Fisher applied 
             // on columns inf:sup of matrix L
             for (int k = 0; k < iter_CMC; k++) {
                 for (int l = inf; l <= sup; l++) {
                     T_temp[k] += log(L[l + nbasis * k]);
                 }
                 T_temp[k] *= -2;
             }  

             // Sort the vector T_temp
             qsort(T_temp, iter_CMC, sizeof(double), cmp);

             // Count the number of elements of T_temp less than T0_temp
             int h = 0;
             while (h < iter_CMC && T_temp[h] < T0_temp) {
                 h++;
             }
// Number of elements of T_temp greater than or equal to T0_temp
count = iter_CMC - h;
pval_asymm_matrix[col + nbasis * row] = (double) count / (double)iter_CMC;
}
// auxiliary variable for columns of L inf:nbasis-1 and 1:sup
int aux_first = 0, aux_second = 0;  
int num_col_needed = 0;

for (int col = row + 1; col < nbasis; col++) {
  T0_temp = 0;
  memset(T_temp, 0, sizeof(T_temp));

  inf = col;
  sup = ((nbasis - row) + col) % nbasis - 1;

  // Useful indexes 
  num_col_needed = nbasis - inf + sup + 1;
  int index_needed[num_col_needed];
  memset(index_needed, -1, num_col_needed * sizeof(int));

  aux_first = inf;
  for (int i = 0; i < nbasis - inf; i++) {
      index_needed[i] = aux_first;
      aux_first++;
  }
  aux_second = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < sup + 1; j++) {
      index_needed[j + nbasis - inf] = aux_second;
      aux_second++;
  }

  // Combining function Fisher applied on p-values 
  // pval[inf:p-1] and pval[0:sup-1]1]
  for (int k = 0; k < num_col_needed; k++) {
        T0_temp += log(pval[index_needed[k]]);
  }
  T0_temp *= -2;

  // Combining function Fisher applied on columns inf:p-1 and 0:sup-1
  // of matrix L
  for (int k = 0; k < iter_CMC; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < num_col_needed; l++) {
        T_temp[k] += log(L[index_needed[l] + nbasis * k]);
    }
    T_temp[k] *= -2;
  } 

  // Sort the vector T_temp
  qsort(T_temp, iter_CMC, sizeof(double), cmp);

 // Count the number of elements of T_temp less than T0_temp
  int h = 0;
  while (h < iter_CMC && T_temp[h] < T0_temp) {
      h++;
  }
// Number of elements of T_temp greater than or equal to T0_temp
count = iter_CMC - h;  
pval_asymm_matrix[col + nbasis * row] = (double) count / (double)iter_CMC;
  } // end for over col from row + 1 to nbasis - 1
 } // end for over rows of asymm p-values matrix except the last row
}

int cmp(const void *x, const void *y)
{
  double xx = *(double*)x, yy = *(double*)y;
  if (xx < yy) return -1;
  if (xx > yy) return  1;
  return 0;
}
```

Here the times of execution in seconds measured in R:

time_original_function
 user   system elapsed
 79.726 1.980  112.817

time_function_double_for
 user   system elapsed
 79.013 1.666  89.411

time_c_function
 user   system elapsed
 47.920 0.024  56.096

The first measure was obtained using an equivalent R function with duplication of the vector pval and matrix L.
What I wanted to ask is some suggestions in order to decrease the execution time with the C function for simulation purposes. The last time I used c was five years ago and consequently there is room for improvement. For instance I sort the vector T_temp with qsort in order to compute in linear time with a while the number of elements of T_temp greater than or equal to T0_temp. Maybe this task could be done in a more efficient way. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced the input size to `p` to 50 to avoid waiting on it (don't have such a fast machine) -- keeping `p` as is and reducing `B` to 100 has a similar effect, but profiling it showed that ~7.5 out of the ~8 seconds used to compute this was spent in the `log` function.

`qsort` doesn't even show up as a real hotspot. This test seems to headbutt the machine more in terms of micro-efficiency than anything else.

So unless your compiler has a vastly faster implementation of `log` than I do, my first suggestion is to find a fast log implementation if you can afford some accuracy loss (there are ones out there that can compute log over an order of magnitude faster with precision loss in the range of ~3% or so).

If you cannot have precision loss and accuracy is critical, then I'd suggest trying to memoize the values you use for `log` if you can and store them into a lookup table.

### Update

I tried the latter approach.

```
// Create a memoized table of log values.
double log_cache[B * p];
for (int j=0, num=B*p; j < num; ++j)
    log_cache[j] = log(L[j]);
```

*Using `malloc` might be better here, as we're pushing rather large data to the stack and could risk overflows.*

Then pass her into `Build_pval_asymm_matrix`.

Replace these:

```
T_temp[k] += log(L[l + nbasis * k]);
...
T_temp[k] += log(L[index_needed[l] + nbasis * k]);
```

With these:

```
T_temp[k] += log_cache[l + nbasis * k];
...
T_temp[k] += log_cache[index_needed[l] + nbasis * k];
```

This improved the times for me from ~8 seconds to ~5.3 seconds, but we've exchanged the computational overhead of `log` for memory overhead which isn't *that* much better (in fact, it rarely is but calling `log` for double-precision floats is apparently quite expensive, enough to make this exchange worthwhile). The next iteration, if you want more speed, and it is very possible, involves looking into cache efficiency.

For this kind of huge matrix stuff, focusing on memory layouts and access patterns can work wonders.

Comment: I have precomputed the log values of the elements of L and also of pval. For me the gain is great!! With p=100 and B=1000 roughly from 90 with R functions sec to 3-9 sec with C function. You saved me a lot of time!! Many thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Glad to be of help. You can also probably go crazy fast with this if you can find a really cache-friendly memory access pattern for this. That's a bit harder, but we can always do more.

Comment: I feel like it is possible to get this down to under a second. Unfortunately the algorithmic details and the math for these kinds of problems are a bit unfamiliar to me and go over my head, so I don't understand exactly how to restructure the data or the access patterns involved with it. But what you want is to try to get the machine to access the memory in a contiguous fashion, and to avoid reloading the same portions of memory unnecessarily into a cache line. If you can manage that, it'll give you even potentially bigger gains than this log optimization...

Comment: Might be a bit overkill though. I enjoy just tuning and tuning these things with a profiler. But a subject you might be interested in is loop tiling for matrices. It might be relevant here.

Comment: Interesting suggestions! In this moment, for the simulations, what I have achieved is good enough. But probably in the future it will be nice to find a cache-friendly solution. For instance,  in the second INTERNAL loop there are two for loops used to calculate the access indexes of L and pval. Is this an example of an implementation which is not cache friendly? I redefine every time the same variables and in some way (I have to try!) I can precompute all the indexes before the more external for loop over the row.

Comment: It's not caching the indices that makes it cache-friendly but actually reorganizing the matrix data (could just be temporarily) so that you're accessing it in a very sequential, left-to-right, 1-dimensional kind of way. Basically you want to avoid jumping around in memory so much, so you don't want to access like index 1, then index 16, then index 2, then 19, or something like that. You want to try to go from index 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 in a sequential fashion, and try to avoid revisiting the same data too much once you get to a distant memory location (like index 200 and back to index 1=bad).

Comment: So it's actually reorganizing the memory representation of the matrix into something that isn't necessarily like a normal matrix representation just for this computation. It might sound expensive, but for these big matrix cases, I've seen people actually transpose a matrix prior to doing multiplication to make it more cache friendly and getting several orders of magnitude speed ups in spite of the extra cost of having to transpose in advance (and including that in the timing).

Comment: If I use images as an example which is more familiar to me, if you're doing a pixel algorithm like blurring which involves accessing neighbors on a huge 4000x4000 image, you get cache misses all over the place on a per-pixel basis when you're accessing the vertical neighbors (since they're 4000 pixels apart in memory). So there you can get substantial speed ups using a blurring algorithm which applies two passes -- a horizontal pass which is cache-friendly (accessing neighbors only 1 pixel memory location apart), then rotate the entire image, then another horizontal blur pass to avoid the...

Comment: ... expensive vertical lookups on a per-pixel basis. Then you rotate/transpose the image again 90 degrees. It sounds like so much more work but the memory that's inside a cache line is so much faster to access, like 3 cycles as opposed to 100 cycles, and you can actually get enormous speed boosts in spite of doing what seems conceptually like so much more work.

Comment: Now the concept is clear. In this site I have found high-quality discussions about cache friendly implementations in C that could be useful in order to improve my solution. Thanks Ike